# How to detect dragging and dropping any element inside TinyMCE editor?

Tags: tinymce

I want to be able to detect dragging and dropping an element inside TinyEditor. When I say inside the editor, I mean only inside, like repositioning an image inside the editor to a new location still inside the editor.

I tried this code:

```
editor.on('dragend', function (e) {
    alert('dragged');
});
```

but it doesn't fire when dropping the dragged element to a new position in the editor, it only fires when the element gets dropped outside the editor.